# What does the EditForm's Context property actually do?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

The standard `EditForm` has a `Context` property. What does this property actually do and how should it be used?

The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editform?view=aspnetcore-7.0) mention `EditContext`. There is no mention of `Context`.

Comment: doesn't the docs mention that? What answer do you expect from us, iwhen not even the docs can give it?

Comment: From the docs: "An EditForm creates an EditContext based on the assigned model instance as a cascading value for other components in the form. The EditContext tracks metadata about the edit process, including which fields have been modified and the current validation messages. Assigning to either an EditForm.Model or an EditForm.EditContext can bind a form to data."

Comment: Any `RenderFragment<T>` which `EditForm` is, can use `Context` to change the name of the Context from `context` to whatever you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It provides the name you can use to reference the instance of the `EditContext` the `EditForm` holds.  If you pass in a `Model` it will also have created it.

In the contrived example below I've added some rather ugly code to show how you could use it.

```
<EditForm Context="xxx" Model="_model">
    @{
        EditContext mycontext = xxx;
        mycontext.Validate();
    };
</EditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Parker mentioned above, you can use the `Context` property to rename what the `context` variable will be called in the namespace of the `<EditForm>`. The context gives you access to the current instance of the `EditContext` without needing to declare it, pass it in (`EditContext` property) and manage it yourself. You can use the `Context` property to prevent name collision if you, or a component you are using also have a variable called `context`.

```
<EditForm Context="context" Model="_model">
    // Assume _success is being set somewhere correctly, not relevant.
    @if (_success && context.GetValidationMessages().Count() == 0)
    {
        // Show success message
    }
    @if (context.GetValidationMessages().Count() > 0)
    {
        // Show errors
    }
</EditForm>
```

I added this answer as I was looking for how to get access to the context and this answer bubbled to the surface and that it might save someone else time in the future.